# How to pass ags to a specific part of an alias

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh

I made my own script to move "up" on unix (cd ..) and it is called like this: 
`$ /path/to/script/myup args | cd` 
where args may be nothing. I would like to alias this to "up" on my tcsh and bash shells so I can call it: `$ up args`. 
I thought it would be aliased like: `alias up '/path/to/script/myup \!*| cd'` because that is what I used for my cdls alias but its not working. How do I properly pass parameters to an alias?

Comment: You don't. You use a function for this. Aliases (at least in not-tcsh) always append their arguments.

Comment: @EtanReisner then why does `alias cdls 'cd \!*; ls'` work?

Comment: Because I said "in not-tcsh" and that's a tcsh alias? I don't know why your `up` alias doesn't work in tcsh. It looks like it should (barring the fact that you didn't escape the `\!` there). Not that I understand what that alias is doing since `ls` doesn't take piped input.

Comment: @EtanReisner That is a typo[fixed], it is escaped in my .cshrc. It is printing task id's when I run how i thought it should be aliased.

Comment: @EtanReisner also that `ls` is not receiving piped input that alias "cd's" to the location then runs ls

Comment: `alias` is somehow bad if it's too complicated. it gives you a fake visual appearance and makes you think it acts the same way in script, while it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you pipe output into `cd`?  `cd` does not read stdin.

Comment: Sorry, not pipe to `ls` pipe to `cd`. The `cdls` alias is fine. Your `up` alias pipes to `cd` though. The lack of a space between the `*` and the `|` may also matter to tcsh I don't know. What does `alias up` output when you run it? And what is the output from `up` when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you mean cd

```
`/path/to/script/myup\\!*`
```

This execute myup and passes its output to cd as a parameter. Note that they are backwards quotes